# Why child component's prop is only showing parent component's initial value?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await, react-router

I am building a react single page app that will call API to search based on a user's input, and the user has to log in to be able to use the app.

The hierarchy of the components are:

1. `App.js` (Handles login and routing)
2. `<SearchPage />` and `<SearchResults />`
3. There are `<SearchNavBar />` and `<SearchMain />` under `<SearchPage />`  (`<SearchMain />` contains the form and input for users to submit, and after submitting, users should be navigated to the route that `<SearchResults />` is at.)

Here is the issue:
Since react only allows one direction data flow, I have to pass user's input from `<SearchMain />` upwards to `App.js`, and then save it in the state of `App.js`, and pass it down as a prop to  `<SearchResults />` together with the token got from `App.js`. However, even I have updated the state in App.js, and passed it as a prop to its child component `<SearchResults />`, while console.logging the props of the child component `<SearchResults />`, I could only get the initial values of the state, not the updated ones, why??

Code:

App.js:

```
const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
       super(props)
    this.state = {
      res:'',
      isLoggedIn:false,
      keyword:''
    }        
    this.handleLogOut = this.handleLogOut.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }    
  handleLogOut(){
    myMSALObj.logout();
    this.setState({isLoggedIn:false})
  }   
  handleSubmit (typedValue){
      this.setState({keyword:typedValue},() => console.log(this.state));//here works just fine, showing correct state value
      window.location.replace('/results')
    };

  async componentDidMount(){

    const idToken_response = await myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    const response = await myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);

    this.setState({isLoggedIn:true,res:response});
  }
  render(){
    return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
        {this.state.isLoggedIn === true ? 
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => <SearchPage 
                                             parentState = {this.state} 
                                             handleLogOut = {this.handleLogOut}
                                             handleSubmit = {this.handleSubmit} />}/>:
        <Route exact path="/" render={() => (<div>Please wait till you are logged in...</div>)}/>}
        <Route exact path="/results" render={() => <SearchResults 
                                                    parentState = {this.state.keyword} 
                                                    handleLogOut = {this.handleLogOut} />}/>          
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
    );
  }
}
export default App;
```

SearchPage:

```
class SeachPage extends Component{

    constructor (props){
        super (props);
        this.state = {
            // userInfo: this.props,
            accessToken: this.props.parentState.res.accessToken,
            name:this.props.parentState.res.account.name,
            email:this.props.parentState.res.account.userName
        }
        // console.log(this.props)
    }
    render(){
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <SearchNavBar 
                 info={this.state} 
                 handleLogOut = {this.props.handleLogOut}/>
                <SearchMain 
                 accessToken={this.state.accessToken } 
                 handleSubmit = {this.props.handleSubmit}/>
            </Fragment>

        )
    }
}

export default SeachPage;
```

SearchMain:

```
class SearchMain extends Component{
    constructor(props){

        super(props);

        this.state = {
            token:this.props.accessToken,
            keyword:'',
            typed:'',
        }

        this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
        this.handleSubmitForm = this.handleSubmitForm.bind(this);

        // console.log(this.props)
    }

    handleChange(event) {
        let typed = event.target.value;
        let keyword = event.target.value;
        this.setState({typed: typed,keyword:keyword},() => console.log(this.state));

      };

    handleSubmitForm(event){
        const keyword = this.state.keyword;
        this.props.handleSubmit(keyword);
        event.preventDefault();
    }

    render(){
        return(
            <div className="container" id="searchBox">
            <form onSubmit = {this.handleSubmitForm } className="field is-grouped"> 
                <p className="control is-expanded">
                <input type="text" className="input" value={this.state.keyword} onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="off" placeholder="Find an asset" required></input>
                </p>
                <p className="control">
                    <button id="button-in-nav-bar" type="submit" className="button is-primary"><strong>Search</strong></button>
                </p>
            </form>
            </div>
        )
    } 

};

export default SearchMain;
```

SearchResults

```
class SearchResults extends Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        console.log(this.props) //here is the issue!! onlyshowing{res:'',isLoggedIn:false,keyword:''}
    }

    render (){
        return(
            <div>test results</div>
        )
    }
};

export default SearchResults;
```

**Update**
So briefly, I was able to pass the keyword upwards to the parent component, just seem to be a little late, the screenshots may better describe my struggle:
[image: App.js]
[image: console]
and if I uncomment the `window.location.replace('/results')` in the first screenshot, the page will be navigated to `'/results'`, and if I `console.log(this.props)` in the render function [image: searchResults.js], the props were displayed 4 times, and the last 2 times had partly correct info.[image], still the keyword was missing... I had a feeling that this might bc of the async nature but I really have zero clue on how to fix it.. (side question, why it was desiplayed 4 times?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Issue**

Using `window.replace` will reload the page and all your state is initialised back to original values. Hence you will lose `keyword` state. 
So you have to wrap your `App` with `Router` and use `history` in `handleSubmit`.

**Second issue**

In `SearchMain`, you are deriving the all the state from props in your state i.e. inside constructor(which gets executed once). Hence, further updates are not available for the `SearchMain` component. 
So just use props (don't use state)

**Updated App.js**

```js
const myMSALObj = new UserAgentApplication(msalConfig);
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      res: {}, //<--- initialise as an empty object(not string)
      isLoggedIn: false,
      keyword: "",
    };
    this.handleLogOut = this.handleLogOut.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  handleLogOut() {
    myMSALObj.logout();
    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: false });
  }
  handleSubmit(typedValue) {
    this.setState({ keyword: typedValue }, () => console.log(this.state)); //here works just fine, showing correct state value
    // window.location.replace("/results");
    this.props.history.replace("/results")
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    const idToken_response = await myMSALObj.loginPopup(loginRequest);
    const response = await myMSALObj.acquireTokenPopup(loginRequest);

    this.setState({ isLoggedIn: true, res: response });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <div>
          <Switch>
            {this.state.isLoggedIn === true ? (
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => (
                  <SearchPage
                    parentState={this.state}
                    handleLogOut={this.handleLogOut}
                    handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit}
                  />
                )}
              />
            ) : (
              <Route
                exact
                path="/"
                render={() => <div>Please wait till you are logged in...</div>}
              />
            )}
            <Route
              exact
              path="/results"
              render={() => (
                <SearchResults
                  parentState={this.state.keyword}
                  handleLogOut={this.handleLogOut}
                />
              )}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
    );
  }
}
export default (props) => (
  <Router>
    <Route render={(rProps) => <App {...props} {...rProps} />} />
  </Router>
);
```

**Updated SearchMain.js**

```js
class SeachPage extends Component{

    constructor (props){
        super (props);
        // this.state = {
        //     // userInfo: this.props,
        //     accessToken: this.props.parentState.res.accessToken,
        //     name:this.props.parentState.res.account.name,
        //     email:this.props.parentState.res.account.userName
        // }
        // console.log(this.props)
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Fragment>
                <SearchNavBar 
                 info={this.props} // <----- use props (not state)
                 handleLogOut = {this.props.handleLogOut}/>
                <SearchMain 
                 accessToken={this.props.accessToken } // <----- use props (not state)
                 handleSubmit = {this.props.handleSubmit}/>
            </Fragment>

        )
    }
}

export default SeachPage;
```

Comment: hi gdh, thanks for your explanation, and I have modified the code according to your example and after submitting the form, however, the page remains the same, only the url changed to '/results', and the `console.log(this.props)` 's result didn't show in the console either.. any thoughts?

Comment: Hi, I just updated the question, I hope this time the question is clearer to you!!

Comment: hi - see the working copy of the code here in sandbox ... https://codesandbox.io/s/parent-child-route-props-passing-issue-fix-jjg61?file=/src/App.js ... console.log is printing properly and everything is working .... carefully see implementation and apply to your code ....in general remember that --  copying props to state means that when this component receives new props the state is not updated (and won't be rerendered)

Comment: Thanks! I think the issue might be the async-await for getting the login info. Thanks for the reminder I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

You console.log props value on contructor method => the data display is first data. You should try console.log on render method. Goodluck!

Comment: Hi Minh, thanks for your reply! I have tried to console.log in the render method but still nothing it's empty. Any further thoughts?

Comment: You said "console.log(this.props) //here is the issue!! onlyshowing{res:'',isLoggedIn:false,keyword:''}". But as i see you only put  "parentState = {this.state.keyword}" to SearchResults as props. So why you can see all state of App.js?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo since I have been debugging back n forth... after removing the '.keyword' then we will have the expected wrong output, sry for the confusion.

Comment: Try replace handleSubmit (typedValue){
      this.setState({keyword:typedValue},() => console.log(this.state))
      window.location.replace('/results')
};To handleSubmit (typedValue){
      this.setState({keyword:typedValue},() => {console.log(this.state))
      window.location.replace('/results')}
};

Comment: Hi Minh, sorry the compiler couldn't recognize the syntax, what do you think the problem was tho?

Comment: Hi Minh, just updated the question, putting concole.log in the render really worked partly, and I was wondering if I have made the question clearer? at the end of the day, I was just trying to use the props in the `searchResults.js`

Comment: Hi. Sorry i was have some busy work. 1. in handleSubmit function, you must put window.location.replace('/results') as a callback like console.log(this.state). It means when setState done, window.location.replace('/results') will called. 2. console.log in SearchResults called 4 times because the props of it is App.js state. It make SearchResults re-render every time App.js state changed. You can try put console.log on App.js render function to check

Comment: Thanks Minh! I will look a bit more into it!!